# php image gallery pagination

Tags: php, pdo, pagination

I am trying to add a simple pagination to an image gallery but I reach a point where I don't get any error messages and it still is not working. I don't know where to look for a mistake.
My code is;

```
<?php 
include 'core/init.php';
ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); // aan of uit
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
?>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
<div id="header">
<h1>Rob Cnossen</h1>
</div>
<div id="titel">
<?php
if (isset($_GET['album_id'])) {
$album_id = $_GET['album_id'];
$album_data = $albums->album_data($album_id, 'name', 'description');

echo '<h2>', $album_data['name'], '</h2>';

$albums = $albums->get_albums();
$images = $images->get_images($album_id);
}
?>
</div>
<div id="sidebarleft">
<?php
if (empty($images)) {
echo 'Er zijn geen foto\'s in dit album';
} else {
foreach ($albums as $album) {
foreach ($images as $image) {
    ?><div id="fotoos"><?php
        if ($image["album"] === $album["id"])
echo'<a href="view_album.php?album_id=', $album["id"],'&image_id=uploads/', $image["album"], '/', $image["img_name"],'"><img src="uploads/thumbs/', $image["album"], '/', $image["img_name"],'" title="" /></a><div id="kruisje"><a href="delete_image.php?image_id=', $image["id"],'">_|</div></a>';
                ?></div><?php                   
}          
}
}
?>
<div id="pagination">
<?php
$count_query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM images where album_id= ?');
$count_query->bindValue(1, $album_id);
try{
$count_query->execute();
}catch (PDOException $e){
die($e->getMessage());
}
$count = $count_query->fetchColumn();

if(isset($_GET['page'])){
$page = preg_replace("#[^0-9]#,",$_GET['page']);
}else{
$page = 1;
}
$limit = 2;
$lastPage = ceil($count/$limit);

if($page<1){
$page = 1;
}elseif($page>$lastPage){
$page = $lastPage;
}
$offset = ($page-1)*$limit;
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT image_id FROM images WHERE album_id= ? ORDER BY image_id DESC
 LIMIT ?,?');
$query->bindValue(1, $album_id);
$query->bindParam(2, $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(3, $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);

try{
$query->execute();
}catch (PDOException $e){
die($e->getMessage());
} 

if($lastPage !=1){

if($page != $lastPage){
$next = $page + 1;
$pagination='<a href="'. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] .'?page='.$next.'">Volgende</a>';  
}
if($page != $lastPage){
$prev = $page - 1;
$pagination.='<a href="'. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] .'?page='.$prev.'">Vorige</a>';
}
}
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {                
    echo $row['image_id'];//This echoes out two image id's, at the moment that is number 75 and 73
}

echo $pagination;
?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

The get_image function is;

```
public function get_images($album_id) {
$images = array();

$count_query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT `image_id`, `image_name`, `album_id`, `timestamp`, `ext` FROM `images` WHERE `album_id`=? ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC");

$count_query->bindValue(1, $album_id);

try{
$count_query->execute();

while ($images_row = $count_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {       
    $images[] = array(
    'id' => $images_row['image_id'],
    'img_name' => $images_row['image_name'],
    'album' => $images_row['album_id'],
    'timestamp' => $images_row['timestamp'],
    'ext' => $images_row['ext']
    );
}
return $images;
}catch(PDOException $e){
die($e->getMessage());
}
}
```

I think there is something wrong in the $pagination variable but I don't know what.I got seven images in this album and the $limit is standing on 2, still all seven images is showing up. And if I click on a pagination link the url shows my that I clicked on a pagination link but that's all. If I click for example vife times on a next or previous link the url can show my this;http://www.robcnossen.nl/view_album.php?album_id=8?page=2?page=2?page=0?page=2?page=0

The site is http://www.robcnossen.nl/view_album.php?album_id=8

I hope you can see what causes the problem.
Thanks...

Comment: There is nothing special with paginating images - it's exactly the same as with any other kind of data. Ans there are A LOT of paginating tutorials over the NET.

Comment: In this line `$images = $images->get_images($album_id);`, Where did you create the `$images` object?

Comment: That is included via core/init.php. I edit the question where you can see now the code of the get_image function.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would either download a working solution from the net and adapt it to your particular situation OR refactor the whole thing taking into consideration some SoC (Separation of Concerns).

- Separate your concerns, leave the logic out of the presentation
- Separate the the pagination logic from the rest. Pagination should only need to know at most 4 things to show its links

  1. the target URL: the links need a homogeneous url scheme, only a `pageNum` in the `url` will change
  2. how many links have to show up (probably an array of `pageNum`s containing the variable part)
  3. [optional] the current ID being viewed, probably to blur out a page
  4. [optional] logic behind `first`/`last`, and behind `prev`/`next`
- Help yourself by cleaning up your code and also encapsulating some functionality. For example:

  ```
  function html_a($href, $content) {
    return '<a href="'.$href.'">'.$content.'</a>';
  }
  function pag_href($url, $id) {
    return sprintf($url,$id);// url: host/target.php?pageNum=%s&someOtherstuff...
  }
  // usage inside loop
  echo html_a(pag_href($url,$id),$pageNum);
  // if you do this right, your pagination code can become reusable
  ```
- use some mysql features to your advantage. You can limit the number of results with `LIMIT`, set the first element of the *page* with `OFFSET`, and still get the total of number of rows with `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`

  ```
  // This way is clearer for me
  $q = 'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS image_id FROM images WHERE album_id=? ORDER BY image_id DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?'
  // after executing your query you may now use pdo's foundRows
  $totalNumEntries = $pdo->foundRows();
  // get number of pages with pageSize
  $totalNumPages = (int)ceil($totalNumEntries / $yourPageSize);
  ```

All in all, try to practice some encapsulation/separation of concerns, do some planning ahead and you won't have to deal with code that not even you want to debug

I'm sorry this does not help with your existing code

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can always try and learn from it. It is looking simple and helpfull...